# React Query React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-query

"I'm relatively new to React Native and currently working with React Query. I've noticed that when I attempt to navigate to another page, there's a noticeable delay specifically related to the React Query API call. Interestingly, when I remove the API call, the navigation works smoothly. Can you provide guidance on how to optimize or restructure my code to improve the navigation speed while still using React Query?"

when I remove the API call, the navigation works smoothly